# How do I get an iframe to only show in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to overlay a YouTube video over a Vimeo video in Firefox only. There is probably a better solution, but the site is a Wordpress site and I am working with a plugin.

It accepts JavaScript. HTML, and CSS.

Basically, I need to create a Firefox only hack for an iframe/embedded video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, basically hiding the iframe in all browsers except FF:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    iframe {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbUUA/) just in case

Also, make sure you keep the CSS I provided in the same order otherwise the `display: none;` will override the FF specific code. Alternatively, you could use `display: block !important;` and the order won't matter, but I've never been a big of `!important` when it isn't necessary...

Comment: You beat me to it LOL

Comment: Thank you guys very much! It is a weird setup the Vimeo iframe is on a different layer (it is a banner slider) so it was hiding that. I switched 'iframe' to 'p' and wrapped it in p tags and now it works. You saved me a lot of stress!